# Perl not subtituting strings with newline

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I have this problem with subtituting characters on perl. My goal is to remove every "." and "-" on my xml. It goes well with the first 4 tags, but it doesnt remove the "." and "-" on the description tag that has a newline on its content.

This is my code:

```
 />([^\000]*?)</g;
 $lastp = $1;
 $lastp =~ s/[\.|\-]*?//g;
 $_ =~ s/(>)[^\000]*?(<)/$1$lastp$2/g;
```

This is my sample data:

```
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>.44.95......</price>
      <publish_date>200.0-10-
      01.</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
```

And here is my output:

```
 <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>4495</price>
      <publish_date>200.0-10-
      01.</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
  </book>
```

Comment: @mkHun No...the regex patterns in fact have `s/`

Comment: Does this code match line-by-line by any chance?  Or is `$_` string the whole XML document/?

Comment: it is line by line and yes $_ string is the whole xml document

Comment: "_it is line by line and yes $_ string is the whole xml document _"  -- by "line by line" I meant that the shown chunk of code works with a single line (being in `$_`), like being inside `while (<>) {...}` or some such. That would explain why it doesn't match fields broken over multiple lines.  So I mean, is `$_` one line (at a time), or the whole document? (Btw, I'd always recommend to work with XML using a library to parse it, not by hand)

Comment: @zdim oh, yes, sorry, it works with a single line, I'd use a library too but we are not allowed to use a library on this one.

Comment: "_it works with a single line_" -- That explains it then: can't find a pattern that spans multiple lines on one line! The line `<publish_Date>200.0-10-` has no `< ` that ends the pattern supposed to match it so the first regex doesn't match, and nor does the last so no substitution can happen.  Btw, then `$1` is `undef` and so the third line tries to bind a regex to an `undef` which should draw a warning -- what tells me that you have no `use warnings;` !  You _always want to have that._ It would've helped directly here.  Anyway: need the whole document in `$_` and take it from there.

Comment: (I mean, need to run all this against a variable that contains the whole XML document.)

Comment: *we are not allowed to use a library on this one* Who is stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$_ =<<'EOS';
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>.44.95......</price>
      <publish_date>200.0-10-
      01.</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
EOS

s/(?<=>)[^<]+/ my $s = $&; $s =~ s#[-.]##g; $s /ge;

print;
```

Output:

```
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>4495</price>
      <publish_date>200010
      01</publish_date>
      <description>An indepth look at creating applications
      with XML</description>
   </book>
```

- The substitution processes the whole lines as a string at once.
- The pattern `(?<=>)[^<]+` matches a string between tags: `(?<=>)` is a
  zero width lookbehind assertion of leading `>` and `[^<]+` matches the
  following sequence of any characters except for `<`. Then the variable `$&` is assigned
  to the matched substring.
- `my $s = $&; $s =~ s#[-.]##g; $s` removes `-` and `.` from the
  matched substring. Then the modified string `$s` is used as the
  `replacement` of the `s/pattern/replacement/` operator thanks to the `e` option.

Comment: (1) I'd add advice to parse XML by libraries, so we don't propagate hand-hacking it  (seems to be a class requirement, not to use libs. Ugh)  (2) Can also do `s/.../ $1 =~ s#[-.]##rg /eg`  -- the `/r` modifier returns the changed string, not changing the original ("non-destructive") so we are allowed to do that to `$1`  (3) Why not use `say`?  (With `use feature 'say';`)